# Como pegar um elemento via jquery em um objeto criado no plugin bootbox.js?

Tags: jquery

Tenho um objeto criado dentro de uma div container-fluid.
Crio o objeto [Bootbox](http://bootboxjs.com/) sem problema algum para gerar um modal *confirm* (código abaixo).

```javascript
$("div.container-fluid").on("click", "button#geraModal", function() {
    bootbox.confirm({
       title: "What is your real name?",
       message: "<div class="row"> <div class="col-md-3>" +
                "<div id="exemplo"> Quero acessar essa DIV </div>" +
                "</div> </div>",
       callback: function(result) {
          if (result === false) {
             alert("Confirm Cancel");
          } else {
             alert("Hi <b>"+result+"</b>");
          }
       }
    });
});
```

Quando tento acessar algum objeto do modal via jQuery não funciona.
Não consigo acessar nenhum elemento do modal via jQuery. Se eu quero executar uma função. Só funciona se eu colocar um Javascript dentro da `div` com um evento `onclick` (por exemplo).

Eu estou tentando acessar a `div` do exemplo acima da seguinte forma:

```javascript
$("div.container-fluid").on("click", "div#exemplo", function() {
    // Faça algo
    alert("Não passa aqui");
});
```

Comment: Você tem certeza que o plugin cria a estrutura da modal dentro de `div.container-fluid` ?

Comment: Eu já tentei acessar diretamente. Não funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema acontece porque quando o manipulador de eventos do Jquery é avaliado o elemento que você referencia ainda não existe (já que é criado dinamicamente). Então você precisa informar ao manipulador de eventos que ele deve combinar o seletor com todos os elementos que existem agora e no futuro. Para isso, utilize o evento `.live`. (http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Seu código ficaria assim:

**Jquery**

```
$("#open").click(function (e) {
    bootbox.confirm({
            title: "BOOTBOX",
            message: '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-offset-1"> <p> Options</p> </div> </div>'+
                            '<div id="row1" class="row text-center center-block"> <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-3 btn btn-default active" id="exemplo1" > <p> Example 1</p> </div> <div class="col-md-3 btn btn-default" id="exemplo2">  <p> Example 2</p> </div></div>',
            className: "saveExample",
            callback: function(result){
                if (result === true){
                    alert("Test 123");
                }
            }
        });
     });

$("#exemplo1").live("click", function(event){
    alert( "Div 'exemplo1' clicada" ); 
});

$("#exemplo2").live("click", function(event){
    alert( "Div 'exemplo2' clicada" ); 
});
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-inverse" id="open">OPEN BOOTBOX</a>
```

Exemplo rodando no [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sLcgvfz9/2/)

---

**Atualização**

O evento `.live()` está depreciado a partir da versão 1.7 do Jquery, utilize o evento `.on()`:

```
$(document).on("click", "#exemplo2", function(event){
    alert( "Div 'exemplo2' clicada" ); 
});
```

O `delegate` também funciona:

```
$(document).delegate("#exemplo1", "click", function(event){
    alert( "Div 'exemplo1' clicada" ); 
});
```

Novo exemplo no [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sLcgvfz9/3/)

Espero tê-lo ajudado.

Comment: Não funciona. O estranho é que se eu colocar na div um atributo onclick ele funciona.

Comment: poderia fazer um exemplo mínimo do seu código no jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Coloquei o exemplo em http://jsfiddle.net/bnascimento/sLcgvfz9/1/

Comment: editei a resposta, veja se resolve seu problema

Comment: `live()` é um método depreciado, a partir da versão 1.7, como consta no documento que você linkou. O correto é o `on()`, altere o início da sua resposta trocando esse método pra deixar correto.